# refresh <table> using AngularJS or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

I'm struggling for some hours now with the `<table>` refresh using onclick button. I want to refresh the random values, once button is clicked. I've set id="myTable" on `<table>` and used .reload() function, but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

**[DEMO on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ng2LH/)**

html:

```
<table id='myTable'> 
    <tr>
      <td id="rand1"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td id="rand2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="parent.document.getElementById('myTable').reload()">Refresh the Random</button>
```

js:

```
var Random = function() {
    return Math.random();
}
document.getElementById("rand1").innerHTML = Random();
document.getElementById("rand2").innerHTML = Random();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<body>
<table id='myTable'> 
<tr>
  <td id="rand1"></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="rand2"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="rand1.innerHTML=Math.random();rand2.innerHTML=Math.random()">Refresh the Random</button>
</body>
</html>
```